# $K(G,1)$ for a torsion-free group $G$

Tags: algebraic-topology

It is known that if  a finite CW complex $X$ is a $K(G,1)$, then the group $G$ must be torsion-free. see proposition 2.45 of Hatcher

Now my question is

If $G$ is a torsion-free group, then is $K(G,1)$ a finite dimensional CW-complex?

Comment: Not necessarily. An easy counterexample is $\mathbb Z^\omega$, but there are even finitely presented torsion free groups with infinite dimensional $K(G,1)$s.

Comment: No. Whether this is possible or not is predicated by "Wall's finiteness obstruction", a K-theory class associated to a CW complex. So if you wanted to check this, one (somewhat unreasonable) way would be to write down a CW complex representing K(G,1) and calculate the finiteness obstruction.

Comment: @MikeMiller Wall's finiteness obstruction can only be used if you can somehow first show that your complex is finitely dominated, though.

Comment: @EspenNielsen: Those are more easily characterized; I recall there being nice (different) characterizations in both Lurie's notes and the original Wall paper.

Comment: @MikeMiller I wonder if you can say which note of Prof Lurie.

Comment: @Jivid I was thinking of Lemma 6 [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/281notes/Lecture2-Wall.pdf), though to be honest I have no idea how you'd ever show 6(c).